# Angular with express, session is not persistent. Each request creates a new session

Tags: node.js, angular, express, passport.js

**Original Question**

I am using passport.js to do authentication in express, when I use req.flash('message', 'message content') in passport strategy, the flashed information is not under the normal session but 'sessions' and when I tried to retrieve the flashed message using req.flash(), it's an empty array.

I printed out the req
, it looks like this:

```
MemoryStore {
     _events:
      { disconnect: [Function: ondisconnect],
        connect: [Function: onconnect] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     sessions:
      { gzNcx9b8rcWfDtJm03VnNJfhsNW8EJ7B:
         '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"flash":{"message":["emails has been taken, choose another one!"]}}' },
     generate: [Function] },
  sessionID: 'ffSa89VCV0Mj6uKLrEPMAdNMGLR2I5ML',
  session:
   Session {
     cookie:
      { path: '/',
        _expires: null,
        originalMaxAge: null,
        httpOnly: true } },
  _passport:
```

Somehow it opens a new session after redirecting to /api/signupFail. Could anyone help me with this?

Here is my middleware setup:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var logger = require('morgan');
var passport = require('passport'); 
require('./config/passport')(passport);
var cors = require('cors');
var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash');  

var app = express();  
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser('Thespywhodumpedme'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

var goalsRoute = require('./routes/goalsRoute');
var userRoute = require('./routes/userRoute');

// required for passport
app.use(flash());
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat',resave: true, saveUninitialized:true})); // session secret

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
 // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session



app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 

app.post('/api/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', { 
  successRedirect: '/api/user/suctest', 
  failureRedirect: '/api/signupFail',
  failureFlash: true
}));
app.get('/api/signupFail', (req, res, next) => { 
  console.log(req.flash('message')); //this is an empty array
  res.status(403).send('fail');
})
```

Here is my strategy setup:

```
module.exports = function(passport) {  
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id);  
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        db.User.getUserById(id, (err, result) => { 
            done(err, result[0]);
        }); 
    }); 

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { 
        if(!email || !password ) { return done(null, false, req.flash('message','All fields are required.')); }
        var salt = '7fa73b47df808d36c5fe328546ddef8b9011b2c6';

        db.User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, rows){  
            if (err) {
                return done(req.flash('message',err));
            } 
            if(rows.length > 0){ 
              return done(null, false, req.flash('message',"emails has been taken, choose another!")); 
            } 
            salt = salt+''+password; 
            var encPassword = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(salt).digest('hex');
            var newUser = {
                name: req.body.name,
                email: email,
                password: encPassword,
                sign_up_time: new Date()
            } 
            db.User.addOneUser(newUser, (err, result) => {
                db.User.getUserByEmail(email, (err, result) => { 
                    return done(err, result[0]);
                }) 
            });
        });
    })); 
};
```

**Update**
At first, I thought it has something to do with flash, but then after printing session out, I found that a new session is created after redirecting. I thought it has something to do with the backend setup. Accidentally, I found this problem doesn't exist when I sent the request from postman. That's when I figured out it might have something to do with Angular which is listening on port 4200 while express listening on port 3000. I was sending the request to port 3000 by hardcoding the port number in httpClient. After I set up a proxy that redirects all API call to port 3000. Everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it turns out that it has nothing to do with the backend. Everything works just fine when I sent the request through postman. The problem is with the frontend, I am using Angular 6, Angular is listening on port 4200 while express listening on port 3000. I set up a proxy in Angular that redirects all API call to localhost: 3000 and the session is persistent.